# CSS modific with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I modify the css:

```
<script>
$("#nomedogame8").click( function() {
$("#nomedogame8").css('position', 'fixed').css('min-width', '100%').css('min-height', '100%').css('right', 0).css('bottom', 0).css('width', 'auto').css('height', 'auto').css('z-index', 8000);
$("#playercontrols").css('z-index', 9000);
$("#playercontrols").show();
});
</script>
```

How i modify again as it was before ?

Comment: Why don't you use two class. And then in click function add new class and again on different click, you can remove that class.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a lot cleaner if you use only addClass, and stick all the css to that class.

But to the question.
You can use: [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$('#nomedogame8, #playercontrols').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#nomedogame8.modified {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 8000;
}
#playercontrols.modified {
    z-index: 9000;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#nomedogame8").click( function() {
    $("#playercontrols").show().add(this).addClass('modified');
});
```

To revert changes:

```
$("#nomedogame8, #playercontrols").removeClass('modified');
```